# Principal ideal domain that is not Euclidean domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

An example of such ring is $\mathbb Z [(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$.
But in the proof, there is something hard to understand.

$ax+by+cz=1$ where $a,b,c,x,y,z$ are integers and $c>1$.
Then why can we write $ay-19bx=cq+r$ for some integers $q,r$ which is less than or equal to $c/2$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $z$ does not intervene in the second equation, we could forget it in the first one and simply write it as $ax + by \equiv 1 \pmod{c}$. This is the hint we need to see that the second equation is simply $ay - 19 bx \equiv r \pmod{c}$. We only have to choose $r$ as the “balanced lift” of $ay - 19 bx \pmod{c}$: we will then always have $r \in [-c/2, c/2]$ and $ay - 19 bx = qc+r$ for some integer $q$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the condition, $ax+by+cz=1$.

It's just elementary number theory.

In general, $ay-19bx=cq+r$, $0 \le r < c$.
But you can adjust the remainder r with the absolute value of r which is less than or equal to $\frac c 2$.

For example, let $ay-19bx=10, c=6$.
Then $10=6\cdot 1+4$, but you can obtain another equation, $10=6\cdot 2-2$.

$2$ (the absolute value of $-2$) is less than or equal to 3 which is$\frac{c}2$ in the above equation.